# Python BGL Draw text in the node editor

Tags: python, node-editor, opengl

I have an operator (MyOperatorTest). How can I make it so that when this operator is run, text is printed on the screen to the top left corner of the node editor? (The operator is in the node editor)

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/how-to-draw-shapes-in-the-node-editor-with-python-bgl showed  how to draw bgl, blf in node editor.  Make the modal operator in @poor 's answer a modal timer operator, you can call it from within your operator,  and display some message on screen for a designated number of seconds, then cancel.