# Use simple text on a 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view

I´m looking for a way to present information (simple text) that can be typed into a panel with text input. The panel is active on the session but it will be displayed on the 3D viewport all the time.
Like this:
[image: simple text overlay 3d window]

On softimage we called these "notes" and it was an extra item on the collection. 
I don´t know where to start looking, since the original code is not part of Blender for doing this. I used this function a lot in softimage.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: If that's *really necessary*, have a look into `bgl` and `blf`: [How to draw shapes with python bgl?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/how-to-draw-shapes-in-the-node-editor-with-python-bgl)

Comment: Could you please help me out on that? After I get to draw a shape, I can just overlay text? How?

Comment: Writing that for you takes a *lot of time*. My spare time is limited so I can't post a complete answer at the moment. Do you already tried to adapt the code of the linked answer? If yes, what part of the code you do not understand?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the closest thing you will get to that is making a text editor window.  Any of the blender panels can be changed to many different windows. One of the options is a text editor.  It won't however, overlay on top of the 3D viewport.