# How to add comments in Blender?

Tags: text-object

I am sending a mesh to my friend to fix. To let him know which places to fix, I have created many `Empty`s at various location named them, `Problem 1`, `Problem 2`, etc. I send him the file along with a text file,

```
Problem 1: Fix texture here.
Problem 2: Fix topology here.
...
```

Is there a way to do this a little more ''integrated''? I want to add "tooltips" or comments at various places in the mesh so that he can see it directly in Blender, instead of him switching between Blender and text editor back and forth.

Please don't suggest to create a text object.

Comment: what about annotations?

Comment: text is not a mesh

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90755/use-simple-text-on-a-3d-view

Answer (score 3):

if you have not hundreds of them you could do this:

Select the vertex, where the problem is.

CTRL-H -> Hook to new object.

[image]

Select "show name".

And change the name of the empty to the problem's text.

result:

[image]

Comment: indeed a creative solution!

Comment: @Blunder: Thank you! I appreciate that!!

Comment: It is a good idea Chris  I'd never have thought of that :)

Comment: Thank you‼️‼️‼️

Comment: Very clever approach to documentation!

Comment: Thank you very much!!!